# Credential filling in cross-origin iFrame

Tags: dom, iframe, google-chrome-extension, autofill, same-origin-policy

The same origin policy prohibits that a top-level domain can access cross-origin iFrames. A browser extension's content script runs in the context of the top-level page (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and thus cannot access an iFrame if it is cross-origin. Is it impossible that a password manager extension can fill in credentials into a cross-origin iFrame? How do password manager vendors handle this?

I guess this is only possible for password managers that are built in to the browser itself, but not for browser extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

`all_frames`

> Optional. Defaults to false, meaning that only the top frame is
>   matched.
>
> If specified true, it will inject into all frames, even if the frame
>   is not the topmost frame in the tab. Each frame is checked
>   independently for URL requirements, it will not inject into child
>   frames if the URL requirements are not met.